# jQuery Debugging using Firebug

Tags: jquery, console.log

I am using this code if jQuery. and its not working where it has to be
I want to debug every line of code by using "console.log"
I am new for this
I have installed firebug for debugging
Can any please tell me how would I use console.log on this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
         $("select").flexselect({ hideDropdownOnEmptyInput: true });
         $("select").flexselect();
         $("input:text:enabled:first").focus();
         $("form").submit(function() {
           alert($(this).serialize());
           return false;
           ;
         });
       });
     </script>
```

Comment: What about `debugger;`???

Comment: if you are using chrome/firefox, goto inpect element on tab scripts select your desired script and add breakpoint on the code.

Comment: will you give few more words of explanation about using console..?

Comment: @MurtazaHussain can u explain me more about adding breakpoint?

Comment: @Jatt.net Nope.  You can debug the jQuery code via breakpoint unless it is not minified.

Comment: Hmm @Praveen.. it can be inserted in browser.. i apologize

Comment: @user3149111 see Praveen's answer. He elaborated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When you press F12, you can see the developer tools either in firebug or native browser tools.

Here  you can place a **`breakpoint`** like in the image below

[image]

If it is an ***`external js`*** file, look for the file in **`source`** tab.

embedded js scripts can be found in **`element`** tab.

Now you can easily debug your scripts.